# Divide by zero error returns for queries with no data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview, sql-server-2012

I'm in the process of trying to figure out a way to solve this divide by zero error.  The current challenge I'm facing comes from [this question I asked not too long ago.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21145232/how-to-accurately-figure-percentage-of-a-finite-total)

Here's the Code I'm using that I'm plugging into reports stretching out into the end of the year:

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND((.01 * 2541) / Count(date_record_entered), 1) AS decimal(5,1)) 
FROM dbo.tablename
WHERE date_record_entered IS NOT NULL 
and date_record_entered >= 20131201 
AND date_record_entered <= 20131231
```

When it comes to current or previous months reports, there aren't any issues with the data populating.  However, when the reports past the current month are accessed, I get the following error in SQL (and a similar error in C#/ASP.NET):

```
Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Divide by zero error encountered
```

Here's what I've tried with no success.

Sample #1

```
SELECT CASE WHEN date_record_entered = 0 then null
ELSE CAST(ROUND(.01 * 2541 / COUNT(date_record_entered), 
AS deciamal (5,1)
FROM dbo.tablename 
WHERE date_record_entered IS NOT NULL 
AND date_record_entered >= 20140201 
and date_record_entered <= 20140228
```

Sample #2

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND((.01 * 2541) / NULLIF(Count(date_record_entered), 1) 
AS decimal(5,1))) 
FROM dbo.tablename 
WHERE date_record_entered IS NOT NULL 
and date_record_entered >= 20140201 
AND date_record_entered <= 20140228
```

Sample #3

```
SET ARITHABORT OFF
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF

SELECT CAST(ROUND(.01 * 2541 / COUNT(date_record_entered ), 1) AS decimal(5,1)) 
FROM dbo.tablename  
WHERE date_record_entered IS NOT NULL 
AND date_record_entered >= 20140201 
and date_record_entered  <= 20140228
```

Now this third one works in SQL but I haven't found a way to do this with a gridview/c#.

I know this may be something really simple but I'm just spinning my wheels at this point.

Comment: Some carriage returns would make the code much easier to read.

Comment: How about adding a `HAVING Count(date_record_entered) > 0` to the end? Since you appear to be checking against `date_record_entered = 0` but dividing by `Count(date_record_entered)`

Comment: Why would date_record_entered ever be 0?  if the field is a date field in the db then I dont think thats possible, it would either be a date, or null.  So if thats the case I would check if its null in your case statement.

Comment: All your samples have syntactical errors.

Comment: @drewlander the `COUNT()` of `date_record_entered` could be 0 due to the `WHERE` criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `NULLIF()` works because dividing by `NULL` returns `NULL`:

```
SELECT CAST((.01 * 2541) / NULLIF(COUNT(date_record_entered), 0) AS DECIMAL(5,1)) 
FROM dbo.tablename
WHERE date_record_entered >= 20131201 
  AND date_record_entered <= 20131231
```

Using `CASE`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(date_record_entered) = 0 THEN NULL
            ELSE CAST((.01 * 2541) / COUNT(date_record_entered) AS DECIMAL(5,1))
       END
FROM dbo.tablename 
WHERE date_record_entered >= 20140201 
  AND date_record_entered <= 20140228
```

Suppressing warnings can usually be avoided.  `date_record_entered` can never be both `NULL` AND be between two dates, so I removed that part of the `WHERE` criteria.

Comment: Looks like your NULLIF function will return null if the count is 1.  I think this needs to be changed to return null if the count is 0 (which would lead to the divide by zero error).

Comment: @GMastros ah thanks, had the `ROUND` and the `NULLIF` flipped, meant to remove the `ROUND()` altogether. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the second solution attempt be ...

`SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(date_record_entered) = 0 then null ELSE CAST(ROUND(.01 * 2541 / COUNT(date_record_entered), AS decimal (5,1)) END FROM dbo.tablename WHERE date_record_entered IS NOT NULL AND date_record_entered >= 140201 and date_record_entered <= 140228`

With a COUNT() in the CASE WHEN

Comment: thats what I was getting at.  Thanks for making it more clear.

Comment: This returns a "Incorrect syntax error near the keyword 'FROM'".

Answer (score 1):

Sample 2 has:  NULLIF(Count(date_record_entered), 1)

Instead, try: NULLIF(Count(date_record_entered), 0)

NULLIF will return the value in the first argument unless it is equal to the value in the second argument.  If they are equal, NULLIF returns NULL.

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND((.01 * 2541) / NULLIF(Count(date_record_entered), 1), 0) AS decimal(5,1))
FROM dbo.tablename 
WHERE date_record_entered IS NOT NULL 
and date_record_entered >= 20140201 
AND date_record_entered <= 20140228
```

Comment: I plugged that in and get an "'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'."

Comment: I was only suggesting that you change the 1 to a 0.  I assumed that your query was already syntactically correct.  Regardless, I have updated my answer with the full query.